# having issues with date validation

Tags: php, validation, date

I'm doing a date validation but it keeps giving me an error message

> Notice: Undefined variable: parts in C:\xampp\htdocs\signup.php on line 15

```
if (empty($_POST['birthday']))
    // the user's date of birth cannot be a null string
    $errors[] = "You must supply a date of birth.";
else if (!strpos("^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$", $_POST['birthday'], $parts))
    // Check the format
    $errors[] = "The date of birth is not a valid date in the " .
        "format DD/MM/YYYY";
elseif (!checkdate($parts[2],$parts[1],$parts[3]))
    $errors[] = "The date of birth is invalid. " .
        "Please check that the month is between 1 and 12, " .
        "and the day is valid for that month.";
elseif (intval($parts[3]) < 1890)
    // Make sure that the user has a reasonable birth year
    $errors[] = "You must be alive to use this service.";
```

Comment: You need this, http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Comment: Please use `{}` to format code and use correct indentation.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you're doing this for fun/experimentation, but if you're actually writing a legitimate program people will use, please use a framework that comes prebuilt with many validation techniques or else you're just asking for security holes (as well as wasting a lot of time)

Comment: I'm doing this for practice and learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just answered something about this last night. You're working way too hard!

PHP has many different validators already. Use the checkdate for validation instead of REGEX

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using the wrong function for regex match.

Use `preg_match("/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/", $_POST['birthday'], $parts)`

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `strpos` is wrong. Check the [strpos manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php).

The third parameter can be used to specify where to start, not to specify a destination array for regular expression pattern matching, where did you get the idea strpos could do that? strpos does not support regular expressions at all.

You should use [preg_match_all](http://www.askaboutphp.com/25/regex-extract-content.html) instead, e.g.:

```
preg_match_all("{^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$}", $_POST['birthday'], $parts);
```

Comment: it didn't work , it show 
Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\xampp\htdocs\signup.php on line 15

Comment: Ah yes forgot that php regular expressions need a delimiter. corrected

Answer (score 0):

You have a fatal mistake that the variable $part only work in first if-statement.
Try to add this after the first if-statement:

```
$part = strpos("^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$", $_POST['birthday'])
```

You also will want to try: [LiveValidation](http://livevalidation.com/) for better validation

Or using this function: [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)